# What query to use ti get recent files from a particular document library - Graph Api

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, microsoft-graph, odata

I'm wondering if anyone has had to do a similar thing to be able to get all recent files from a particular site collection of sharepoint library

To get lists used i know i can use this - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/insights/used

I tried the below to get recent files from a particular site collection of sharepoint library
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/{documentLibraryId}/recent](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/%7BdocumentLibraryId%7D/recent)

But it doesn't like it and doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try the use the below GRAPH API to get the last modified items (recent items) from the library,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/drives/<Library drive ID>/list/items?$orderby=lastModifiedDateTime desc
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Shantha for the response and i can get the full list. but how can i filter it by the logged in user?